# How to indent XML files automatically when opened in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: xml, sublimetext2, indentation

I'm using Sublime Text 2 (with the Indent XML plugin) for editing XML files.

How can I configure Sublime Text to automatically execute the "Indent XML" action right after opening a file named *.xml?

Comment: Did you finally find out how to do that?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't.

Comment: "indentX"  worked for me better than "indent xml"

Answer (score 110):

To indent / prettify / beautify XML, I use [SublimeText Indent](https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml) plugin:

1. Install the package with Package Control (search "indentxml").
2. Open any XML file, or create a new file and paste any XML into it.
3. Ctrl-K, F to indent it.

Comment: This no longer works post python 2.6, see [here](https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml/issues/16#issuecomment-103552283)

Comment: Works with Sublime Text 3. Use IndentXML.

Comment: command + shift + p > search package control: install pacakge > indentxml (for newbies)

Comment: Use (Command + K, Command + F) on mac or check the "Selection" menu.

Comment: In Linux use Ctrl + K + F (Sublime Text 3)

Comment: I cannot find this package in the package control palette. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm on build 4107 and I cannot find it either.

Answer (score 9):

Try this plugin:

1) Tools > New Plugin

2) Copy and paste code below

3) Save in the Packages/User directory with a .py extension (should be the default directory)

4) Open any XML file and it should run. [Open console (Ctrl+~ in Windows) to see any errors]

The code supports both "Indent XML" and "IndentX". If they don't exist I believe the command fails silently and shouldn't affect anything. I'm a plugin newbie but hope this helps!

```
# Packages/User/AutoIndent.py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class OnOpenCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):  
  def on_load(self, view):  
    if view.file_name().lower().endswith(".xml") :
      #print "{0}: Auto indenting {1} with Indent XML's auto_indent command".format(__file__, view.file_name())
      view.run_command("auto_indent")       
      #print "{0}: Auto indenting {1} with IndentX's basic_indent_tags command".format(__file__, view.file_name())
      view.run_command("basic_indent_tags")
```